# mouseover doesn't work when I try to automate using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying automating a website and I'm trying to access a *menu > submenu* and perform a click on the item in *submenu*. After a lot of search I learned that **mouseover** is a better option for me as the *submenu* only appear if I hover the mouse on the menu. I have tried many instances but the mouse just won't hover on the main *menu* and to *submenu*. The code is:

```py
policymngmt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/div/main/site-header/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a')
issuance = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/div/main/site-header/div[3]/div/div[1]/nx-link/a')
        
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(policymngmt).move_to_element(issuance).click().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try the below*

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)

policymngmt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")

hover= ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(policymngmt)
hover.perform()


WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/div/div/main/site-header/div[3]/div/div[1]/nx-link/a"))).click()
```

***Imports***

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the mouse still does not hover on main menu, are there any other options to solve this. Thank you

Comment: Re-check the locator of your element, what error are you getting ?

Comment: i am getting Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/app-root/div/div/main/site-header/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a"} error. When i right click on policy management and click inspect element, i copy paste the xpath in policymngmt variable

Comment: Can you share the `HTML` source for the element

Comment: sure... the HTML is <a _ngcontent-ngc-c49="" class="active--" href="/allianz-modular-products/new-e-schedule-select-agent-code"> Policy Management </a>

Comment: Try these `xpath` with above solution 
`//*[contains(text(),'Policy Management')]`
**OR**
`//*[normalize-space()= 'Policy Management']`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i have tried many many instances over the days and also the solution you gave but nothing worked, i really got frustrated but never gave up, finally after days i found the solution where currently i am using pyautogui function to hover using xy coordinates and perform click. it is working well sofar, i really would like to thank you for the help you offered